# Multi-dimensional array search to preserve parent

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter, vtiger

### TL;DR

I have this data: [var_export](http://pastebin.com/aUEpH7fG) and [print_r](http://pastebin.com/3iTDUUgw).

And I need to narrow it down to: http://pastebin.com/EqwgpgAP ($data['Stock Information:'][0][0]);

How would one achieve it? (dynamically)

---

I'm working with vTiger 5.4.0 CRM and am looking to implement a function that would return a particular field information based on search criteria.

Well, vTiger is pretty weakly written system, looks and feels old, everything comes out from hundreds of tables with multiple joins (that's actually not that bad) etc., but job is job.

The need arose from getting `usageunit` picklist from Products module, Stock Information block.

Since there is no such function as `getField();`, I am looking forward to filter it out from Blocks, that is actually gathering the information about fields also.

`getBlocks();` then calls something close to `getFields();`, that again something close to `getValues();` and so on.

So...

```
$focus = new $currentModule(); // Products
$displayView = getView($focus->mode);
$productsBlocks = getBlocks($currentModule, $displayView, $focus->mode, $focus->column_fields); // in theory, $focus->column_fields should/could be narrowed down to my specific field, but vTiger doesn't work that way

echo "<pre>"; print_r($productsBlocks); echo "</pre>"; // = http://pastebin.com/3iTDUUgw (huge dump)
```

As you can see, the array under the key `[Stock Information:]`, that actually comes out from translations (yada, yada...), under `[0][0]` contains information for `usageunit`.

Now, I was trying to `array_filter();` the data out from there, but only thing I've managed to get is `$productsBlocks` stripped down to only contain `[Stock Information:]` with all the data:

```
$getUsageUnit = function($value) use (&$getUsageUnit) {
    if(is_array($value)) return array_filter($value, $getUsageUnit);
    
    if($value == 'usageunit') return true;
};
            
$productsUsageUnit = array_filter($productsBlocks, $getUsageUnit);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($productsUsageUnit); echo "</pre>"; // = http://pastebin.com/LU6VRC4h (not that huge of a dump)
```

And, the result I'm looking forward to is http://pastebin.com/EqwgpgAP, that I've manually got by `print_r($productsUsageUnit['Stock Information:'][0][0]);`.

---

How do I achieve this? (dynamically...)

Comment: I doubt that there are any pros in vTiger scene, sometimes while reading the source, you start to wonder, whether developers themselves have an idea how it all works together.

Comment: ;) that's the problem with many systems / On what condition do you decide `['Stock Information:'][0][0]` is what you want?

Comment: On: `['Stock Information:'][0][0][2] == 'usageunit'`.

Comment: Could you add another *paste* using `var_export` makes copying your input data a lot easier ;)

Comment: See edited **TL;DR** for `var_export` link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function helper($data, $query) {
  $result = array();

  $search = function ($data, &$stack) use(&$search, $query) {
    foreach ($data as $entry) {
      if (is_array($entry) && $search($entry, $stack) || $entry === $query) {
        $stack[] = $entry;
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  };


  foreach ($data as $sub) {
    $parentStack = array();
    if ($search($sub, $parentStack)) {
      $result[] = $parentStack[sizeof($parentStack) - 2];
    }
  }

  return $result;
}

$node = helper($data, 'usageunit');
print_r($node);
```

Comment: The result equals the result of my `array_filter()` callback function `$getUsageUnit` noted in Q, resulting in `block` data (whole of 'Stock Information:') not field data (only the array that contains a subarray of value 'usageunit').

Comment: I see, wasn't too sure how narrow the result should be. (updating soon)